# Apache2: PRNG still contains insufficient entropy

Tags: ssl, apache2

I have an issue that my website is not served correctly over ssl (only sometimes / by random). When the website is not served I am getting the following record in my apache error log:

> [ssl:warn] [pid 1849] AH01990: PRNG still contains insufficient
>   entropy!

Do you have any idea where to search for the issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: /dev/urandom or /dev/random had a very low entropy level. In my case this issue was related to my virtualisation container.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have the /dev/urandom fallback specified:

```
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed startup "file:/dev/urandom" 1024
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect "file:/dev/urandom"  1024
```

And ensure you have a random entropy seeding application like `haveged` or `rng-tools` installed.

Apache will then fall back to using `/dev/urandom` when its builtin has insufficient entropy.